# Boot off of an external hard drive

Tags: macos, hard-drive, startup, partition

I made 2 partitions on my external hard drive. One is 240ish GB and one is 10GB. I put the OS X Lion install image on the 10GB partition (using restore) and when that finished I tried to boot from that hard drive but it doesn't show up, just my regular hard drive that is in my computer.

I am on a mid-2012 MacBook Pro running macOS Sierra

Comment: Which version of Lion? That machine needs at least 10.7.3

Comment: Version 10.7.5 I got the image from here: http://macdrug.com/download-mac-os-x-lion-10-7-5-dmg-iso-image/

Answer (score 1):

It's probably the lion image. try a different image. Try to google : "index of" Install OS X Lion

then click on some of the links and once the dmg download is complete get the installesd.dmg from the image and burn it using disk utility

Comment: I found this website: https://server.ferrante.me/shared/index.php?dir=Shared/Apple/Mac/MountainLion/Install%20OS%20X%20Mountain%20Lion.app/Contents/SharedSupport/ And I am now installing the 'InstallESD.dmg' file and I will get back to you to let you know if it works.

Comment: When booting from the hard drive with the installesd.dmg file I get the prohibited sign. (\)